# How do i display user input captured from a list in C#

Tags: c#, list, loops, user-input

How do I access items added to a list, thats in a loop in C#?

This method gets user input for a recipe and adds it to a list but in another method i wish to display ingredient name, quantity and unit of measurement WHEN the user enters the "recipeName" i have another method that does this but it only displays the last recipe details captured by the user instead of the recipe details for any recipe they choose(PS. an unlimited amount of recipes should be able to be entered).

```
//method that gets the users input about ingredients and step descriptions for recipe ...
        public void RecipeDetails()
        {
            recipeCount = 0;
            caloriesTotal = 0;

            int ingredient_count = 0;
            int s = 0;
            steps = 0;
            maxIngredients = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Name of recipe : ");
            recipeName = Console.ReadLine();
            recipeNames.Insert(recipeCount, recipeName);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Number of ingredients : ");
            maxIngredients = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            maxIngredientCount.Insert(recipeCount, maxIngredients);


            // Loop to get ingredients ...
            while (ingredient_count < maxIngredients)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter name of ingredient " + (ingredient_count + 1) + ":");
                ingredient_name = Console.ReadLine();
                ingredientNames.Insert(ingredient_count, ingredient_name);

                //error handling to prevent users from entering a value other than numeric. 
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter quantity of " + ingredient_name + " : 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 :");
                    quantity = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    ingredientQuantities.Insert(ingredient_count, quantity);
                }
                catch (FormatException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Numeric values only ! ");
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter quantity of " + ingredient_name + ": ");
                    quantity = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    ingredientQuantities.Insert(ingredient_count, quantity);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Enter unit of measurement for " + ingredient_name + ": Single, Bunch, Tsp, Cup ");
                unit_measure = Console.ReadLine();
                ingredientUnits.Insert(ingredient_count, unit_measure);

                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                Console.WriteLine("- A calorie is a unit of energy commonly used to measure the amount of energy in food and the energy expended through physical activity -");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.WriteLine("Enter amount of calories for " + ingredient_name + ": ");
                calorie = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                calories.Insert(ingredient_count, calorie);

                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                Console.WriteLine("- A food group is a category of foods that share similar nutritional properties -");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the food group " + ingredient_name + " belongs to. (Fruit, Vegetables, Grains, Protein or Dairy) : ");
                foodGroup = Console.ReadLine();
                foodGroups.Insert(ingredient_count, foodGroup);

                caloriesTotal += calorie;
                ingredient_count++;
            }

            // Loop to get steps and descriptions ...
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number of steps : ");
            steps = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            while (s < steps)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter description of step " + (s + 1));
                description = Console.ReadLine();
                stepsDescriptions.Insert(s, description);
                s++;
            }
            recipeCount++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

with the lack of information, see if this can help :

```
public List<Item> Itens { get; set; }           
 

   
new Item { Product = laptop, Quantity = 1, UnitValue= 500 },
new Item { Product = tv, Quantity = 2, UnitValue= 100 }

 public string ToString()
 {
 var invoice= new StringBuilder();
 foreach (var item in Itens)
 {
 var invoice = new StringBuilder();
 invoice.AppendLine($"{item.Product.Name} \t|{item.Quantity}\n|{item.UnitValue} ");
  }
 return invoice.ToString();
 }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have uploaded all my code on github. The user enters the info for each recipe when the code is run, the problem is each time the user enters a new recipe, it is saved to memory and the old info is saved in the list so some how that info needs to be linked to that specific recipename and is able to be displayed when the user enters that recipes name                                                                                                                                                  https://github.com/Avishh7/RecipeApplication.git